# How to create an image strip with HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: html, css, html5-animation

I want to make horizontal strip of image thumbnails using HTML5 and CSS3. and scroll it horizontally. can anyone tell me how do i proceed?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the css:

```
<div style="white-space:nowrap; overflow-x: scroll">
<img><img><img> <!-- Images here -->
</div>
```

nowrap prevents contents from wrapping, and overflow-x: scroll causes overflows in the x-direction to have a scroll bar